# I am Trying to extract Publish Data and Publish Time in separate column form Publish_time, I did extract data but I can't extract time

Tags: r, date, time

[publish_time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/41Vqk.png)

[New Publish_Date Dand Publish_Time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZQH0D.png)

```
DatasetName:BigData
BigData$Publish_DateD<-as.Date(BigData$publish_time)#add Publish_DateD

BigData$Publish_Time<- format(as.POSIXct(BigData$publish_time),format="%H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way how we could do it, with an example data set using the first two rows of your data. We use `parse_date_time()` function and then `separate`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(publish_time = parse_date_time(publish_time, order = "ymd_HMS")) %>% 
  separate(publish_time, c("date", "time"), sep = " ") 
  # uncomment to get date and period class
  # mutate(date = ymd(date), 
  #        time = hms(time))
```

output:

```
  date       time    
  <chr>      <chr>   
1 2018-06-14 00:04:33
2 2018-06-14 00:00:03
```

or:
if you uncomment the last two lines you will get date and period class

```
  date       time    
  <date>     <Period>
1 2018-06-14 4M 33S  
2 2018-06-14 3S
```

data:

```
df <- structure(list(publish_time = c("2018-06-14T00:04:33.000Z", "2018-06-14T00:00:03.000Z"
)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```